# Exportieren an Ägypten

Tags: verb, adverb, verb-usage

Ich habe folgende Überschrift im Spiegel Online gelesen und mich gefragt, ob diese Korrekt ist

> Trotz Verbot: Zwölf EU-Staaten exportieren Waffen an Ägypten

Soweit ich weiß müsste es

> [...] exportieren Waffen nach Ägypten

heißen, oder irre ich mich?

[SPON-Link](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/aegypten-eu-staaten-liefern-waffen-trotz-lieferstopp-a-1094001.html)

Answer (score 3):

"Exportieren nach" ist richtig. Der Artikel möchte mit der Wortwahl vermutlich ausdrücken, dass die Waffen an den Staat Ägypten gehen, nicht an irgend einen anderen Empfänger in Ägypten.

Die Formulierung "exportieren an" scheint gelegentlich verwendet zu werden, wenn man den genauen Empfänger des Exports benennt:

> Wir exportieren an Apotheken [...] sowohl innerhalb der EU, als auch in Drittländer. ([Quelle](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=exportieren+an))

Ob das offiziell als korrekt gilt, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: ich denke, hier waren die Schreiber in Gedanken bei "liefern ... an"

Answer (score 2):

Exportieren ist eine Alternative zu Liefern.
Wenn man sagt "Ich liefere Waffen nach Ägypten", meine ich damit nur, dass der Empfänger in Ägypten ist. Sagt man hingegen "Ich liefere Waffen an Ägypten", dann wird damit klar ausgedrückt, dass ich die Regierung von Ägypten meine und nicht die geografische Position.

Comment: Aber Synonyme verwenden nicht immer die gleichen Adverbien. Wenn ich nach ``"exportieren an"`` in Google suche, finde ich neben dieser Frage nur Informatikartikel, die sich auf das Anwählen von Schaltflächen beziehen oder an im Sinne von am PC...

Comment: @Armin: Wie würdest du denn das Verb *exportieren* zusammen mit der Angabe eines Empfängers wie "die ägyptische Regierung" in einem kurzen Satz verwenden? (Davon unabhängig ist *an* natürlich kein Adverb.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper gar nicht. Liefern erfüllt die Aufgabe ausgezeichnet. Oder auch ``12 EU-Staaten handeln mit Waffen mit ägyptischer Regierung trotz Verbot``